# How to replace a JSON object value {} in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript, object

I have the following JSON object data stored in a JSON file, which will be passed as a when performing an API call.

I want to replace "it-goes-here" with below {} block.

replaced-data:

```js
{
    "parenturl":"xxx.com",
    "username":"userId",
    "password":"xxx!",
    "id":"id",
    "url":"xxx.com",
    "xxx":"xxx"
}
```

test.json

```
{
  "details": it-goes-here,
  "dbs": [
    {
      "schemas": [
        {
          "schemaName": "schemaName",
          "tables": [
            {
              "tableName": "tableName",
              "type": "table",
              "columns": [
                {
                  "name": "name",
                  "gender": "F",
                  "canDonate": true,
                  "database": "database"
                },
                etc.,
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
}
```

I have tried the code below, but it keeps giving me *SyntaxError: Unexpected token
in JSON at position 28*. I'm new to nodeJS, what am I doing here? What else can I try?

```js
let data = await fs.readFileSync('./test/test.json', 'utf8').toString();
data = await JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data).replace('it-goes-here', 'replaced-data'));
```

Comment: it would better to convert data into object first then modify the data.

Comment: `let data = await fs.readFileSync('./test/test.json', 'utf8')toString();`
this line, before toString() need a 'dot'

Comment: My bad. It's a mistake in the post.

Comment: Don't manipulate JSON-string. Parse the data to JSON and manipulate the data on the objects. But your `test.json` is not a valid JSON because `"details": it-goes-here,` is invalid. Furthermore`await JSON.parse(...)` makes no sense, as `JSON.parse()` is not async ...

Answer (score 0):

Try read and parse the `test.json` to JSON Object and run `data.details = replacedData` to replace the `details` object to `replacedData` object.